# Powershell List Excel Files and Copy

Tags: powershell, copy, get-childitem

I apologize for the naivety of this post, please forgive my newness.

I have approximately 20,000 network files to filter through and copy certain ones to a local drive.

File List Requirements:

- Excel files of various type (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm)
- Only files modified after 4/1/2022
- Only files that contain "2022" in the filename

If the file meets those requirements then:

- Copy the file to a local folder (original folder path structure doesn't matter, all files can go in one folder)
- Output the original path and filename to a txt file, along with the lastwritedate

I have created the following code, which successfully obtains all excel files and creates the filename list

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\network_folder\" -Filter *.xls -Recurse | Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\local_folder\file_list.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

However I cannot figure out the following issues:

- how and where to filter for the lastwritetime
- how and where to filter for the "2022" in the name
- how and where to copy the files to the local folder
- right now I'm just putting this all in the command line, do I need to make some file to run this process?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: When you crosspost the same question at the same time to different forums you should at least post links to the other forums along with your question to avoid people willing to help you making their work twice or more.Thanks [PowerShell.org forum - Powershell List Excel Files and Copy](https://forums.powershell.org/t/powershell-list-excel-files-and-copy/21217/1)

Comment: When you say _" all files can go in one folder"_, you're bound to have naming collisions.. Have you thought about that?

Comment: Good point on the collisions Theo.  I guess it would be best to preserve the original folder structure in the destination folder.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this.
It searches for files in the source folder with `2022` in the name and having .xls (or anything following xls) as extension.

It then loops over these items, creates the subfolder structure where they were found in the destination folder, copies the files and finally writes out a CSV file with information of the original file.

```
$sourcePath  = 'D:\network_folder'
$destination = 'D:\dest_folder'
$refDate     = [datetime]::new(2022,4,2)  # --> next day date as of midnight

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*2022*.xls*' -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $refDate} | ForEach-Object {
        # create the destination folder if it does not already exist
        $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourcePath.Length)
        $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory -Force
        # copy the file
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target
        # output the wanted properties from the original file
        $_ | Select-Object Name, FullName, LastWriteTime
    } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\local_folder\file_list.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```